# Google Sheets / Javascript Pasting Issue

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am using Google Sheets copyTo function.  There are formulas in cells M2:P10 that are calculating a value from another sheet.  I'm simply trying to use the copyTo function to paste the values to another sheet, but the pasting function results in blank output.  I can't figure out why as everything seems perfectly fine here.  Help!

```
 var id = "1I7Ptwg26W_WrLty9y7U-8c8kGKS9t8aw3SF-M2JwgJ1";
 var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName('Converted Data');
 var ss5 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName('PastedConverted');
 ss2.getRange('M2:P10').activate();
 ss2.getRange('M2:P10').copyTo(ss5.getRange("M2:P10"), {contentsOnly:true});
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Also - just to add, I've also tried the SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES method and got the exact same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I am unsure why this works but not the other way around, but figured I'd give you what worked for me:

```
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('MyPage'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('M:AB').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'MyPage\'!M:AB').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
```

Comment: Why are you using the activate function? is there any reason for that?

Answer (score 0):

Although you have already posted an answer I think that the way you solved your problem is not the most optimal one.

Just to illustrate how the method [`copyTo()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination) works.

You have an `origin` rang (the range you want to copy from) in which you invoke the `copyTo()` and the `target`(the place you want to copy to) as the input parameter.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss1 = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var ss2 = ss.getSheets()[1];

  var origin = ss1.getRange("A1:A5");
  var target = ss2.getRange("A1:A5");

  origin.copyTo(target);

}
```

Adittionaly you can add more options to copy just the thing you need with the [`CopyPasteType`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/copy-paste-type).